# How to post the Image and Text in Facebook using Share Intent

Tags: android, android-facebook, android-sharing

I am using share intent to post the image and text in Social media App. I am using following code

```
String shareName=advdetails.get(0).getBusinessname();
String description=advdetails.get(0).getDescription();
Uri image = Uri.parse(advdetails.get(0).getBusinesslogo());

Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, description);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, image);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, shareName));
```

The above description, image and ShareName are getting from the **pojo** class.

When I am trying to share these data into Facebook, I am getting the information as **"One or more Media items could not be added"**

Comment: could you please replace `image` with Uri.parse("full path of the image") and check if the code is working for you?

Comment: possibly useful: https://hasithdevs.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/android-share-textimages-using-share-intent/